# export_media from Google Drive API don't write newlines

Tags: python, google-drive-api, export, google-docs

When I try to export the text from a Google Docs using the `export_media` method, the result is a bloc of text (correct at least) but without newlines.

For exemple, if my file contains

> Test
>
> And another test

The display will looks like

> Test And another test

Here is my code:

```
http = decorator.http()
service = discovery.build("drive", "v2", http=http)
docs = service.files().export_media(fileId=docs_key, mimeType="text/plain").execute()
docs = docs.decode('utf-8')
```

EDIT:

I also tried to export the file as html content instead of text. The problem is that I don't how to use this html as actual html instead of just a string. Here is my code :

```
http = decorator.http()
service = discovery.build("drive", "v2", http=http)
docs = service.files().export_media(fileId=docs_key, mimeType="text/html").execute()

docs = docs.decode('utf-8')
docs = docs.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
h = HTMLParser()
docs = h.unescape(docs)
```

As you can see, `docs` contains now the google document in an html format. But if I try to display `docs` like this, my web page display this time the html code (still without newlines) :

```
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"><style type="text/css"> ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-0{list-style-type:none}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-3 > li:before{content:"❏ "}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-4 > li:before{content:"❏ "}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-2{list-style-type:none}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-1{list-style-type:none}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-5 > li:before{content:"❏ "}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-1 > li:before{content:"❏ "}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-7 > li:before{content:"❏ "}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-0 > li:before{content:"✓ "}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-6 > li:before{content:"❏ "}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-8 > li:before{content:"❏ "}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-8{list-style-type:none}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-7{list-style-type:none}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-4{list-style-type:none}.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-2 > li:before{content:"❏ "}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-3{list-style-type:none}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-6{list-style-type:none}ul.lst-kix_yreqa03lukup-5{list-style-type:none}</style></head><body style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:72pt 72pt 72pt 72pt;max-width:451.3pt"><p style="padding:0;margin:0;color:#000000;font-size:11pt;font-family:"Arial";orphans:2;widows:2"><span>First Online edit : 15h50</span></p></body></html>
```

Of course, I want to display the generate html as the webpage, and not the string it's actually showing.

Comment: There is nothing in the API that you can use to influence formatting, so you're kinda hosed. The only workaround I can think of would be to export as html and then parse the html into text yourself, or find a library that does it.

Comment: Well I already tried to do so but the html parsed was written as text on my website. I didn't find anything to make it read as actual html instead of a string. Any ideas about that ?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your comment. perhaps you could paste the html output into your question.

Comment: Ok, I edited my question, hope it will be more understandable

Comment: so I can see that you're exporting a valid HTML document. You should ask a new question on SO like "is there a python library to parse an HTML document"